# Place diffs depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I have a site with jquerymobile, at the moment optimized for mobile devices. Content- wise I work especially with collapsible's, and fill the content for that dynamically via javascript.

Now I want to create a responsive design, taking some of the div's out of their "collapsible set's" and place them differently for larger screen sizes- for example:

Mobile view:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible"><div id="content1"></div></div>
    <div data-role="collapsible"><div id="content2"></div></div>
</div>
```

Desktop view:

```
<table><tr><td>
    <div id="content1"></div></td><td>
    <div id="content2"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

What would be the best way to accomplish that without having to create the layout twice and hide/show the correct one depending on the media query?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: You could add items depending on window width `if $(window).width() > 480) { add table } else { add collapsible }`

Comment: I ended up filling the whole content depending on the screensize - similar to your suggestion... Thanks ;)